# AuthorizationException while sending a payment request with braintree on Sandbox

Tags: c#, .net, braintree

No matter what I do I'm always getting the same AuthorizationException for the following request on sandbox with valid keys:

REQUEST:

```
{"CreditCard": 
  {
   "CVV":"123",
   "ExpirationMonth":"10",
   "ExpirationYear":"2016",
   "Number":"4111 1111 1111 1111"
  },
 "Amount":195.000000,
 "OrderId":"bb461ebb-b894-4716-9ea2-7317f9e8c8d9",
 "MerchantAccountId":"xxxxx",
 "TaxAmount":0,
 "Type":{},
 "CustomFields":
  {
    "correlation_id":"bb461ebb-b894-4716-9ea2-7317f9e8c8d9"
  },
 "Options":
  {
    "StoreInVault":true,
    "SubmitForSettlement":true
  },
 "CustomerId":"2012f124-2f00-477f-85fb-f6bc3f5fe275"
}
```

Here's the code that I'm using to create this request:

```
    var request = new TransactionRequest
    {
        OrderId = message.Id.ToString(),
        Amount = message.Amount,
        CustomerId = message.CustomerId.ToString(),
        MerchantAccountId = message.MerchantAccountId,
        Options = new TransactionOptionsRequest
        {
            SubmitForSettlement = message.SubmitForSettlement
        }
    };

    string expirationMonth = message.ExpirationMonth.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string expirationYear = message.ExpirationYear.GetValueOrDefault().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    request.CreditCard = new TransactionCreditCardRequest
    {
        Token = message.CreditCardId.ToString(),
        CardholderName = message.CardholderName,
        Number = message.CardNumber,
        ExpirationMonth = expirationMonth,
        ExpirationYear = expirationYear,
        CVV = message.CVV
    };

    request.Options.StoreInVault = true;

    var result = _gateway.Transaction.Sale(request);
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have any other questions, feel free to [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) directly.</sub>

This error can happen when you're attempting to use a merchant account that your user doesn't have access to. In this case, the merchant account ID you're passing (which you X'd out above) doesn't exist.

Take a look at [our support pages](https://support.braintreepayments.com/customer/portal/articles/1080468-merchant-id-vs-merchant-account-id-what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-) for more information on merchant account IDs:

> ### Merchant Account ID
>
> With Braintree, you can have multiple merchant accounts processing via the same single gateway account. You could have multiple locations, multiple businesses, and multiple currencies all setup and processing under one single account. This makes it easy to keep track of all of your processing with unified reporting and access and can even save you money.
>
> You can find the values for all merchant accounts in your gateway account by following these steps:
>
> > - Log in to the Control Panel
> > - Navigate to Settings -> Processing
> > - Scroll to the bottom of the page to find the section labeled Merchant Accounts
>
> ### If I only have a single merchant account, do I still need to send this value with API requests?
>
> No, this is an optional value with all API requests that support it. If you only have a single merchant account, there's no need to include this value. If you have more than one merchant account you can specify which merchant account should be used with each API request. If you omit this value, all requests will automatically be routed through your default account.